# Editors opening on top of IPageLayout

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am using the 3.x-4.x compatibility layer and have the following configuration in my `IPerspectiveFactory.createInitialLayout` method:

```java
String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);    

// NavigationView
layout.addStandaloneView(NavigationView.VIEW_ID, 
    true, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.20f, editorArea);
layout.getViewLayout(NavigationView.VIEW_ID).setCloseable(false);
layout.getViewLayout(NavigationView.VIEW_ID).setMoveable(true);

topRightFolder = layout.createFolder("perspective.toprightfolder", IPageLayout.TOP, 0.25f, editorArea);   
topRightFolder.addView("myView");
topRightFolder.addPlaceholder("my.code.*"); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

All views that begin with `my.code.*` will open at the top of the Page Layout and will stack in tabs as each subsequent one is selected. I also have a couple different editors in my navigation view and when they open, they are positioned at `0.26f` from the top of the page, as expected.

My question is this: Is there any way to configure the page layout so that editors behave like views and open at the top of the `IPageLayout`? I noticed that when an editor opens, I can drag it to the top of the page layout, so it made me wonder is there a way to default the editor to open at the top?

Answer (score 0):

No. When using Eclipse 3.x compatibility layer editors always open in the editor area.